# Resident Evil parody animation with Jill fighting Nemesis

Tags: story-identification, animation, resident-evil

In 2023, I ran into a cartoon animation involving Jill Valentine fighting [Nemesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemesis_(Resident_Evil)), I think on Facebook. It looked like it was in a hand-drawn style, with fairly fluid, if cartoonish, animation (it reminded me a bit of the old Flash animations on places like Newsgrounds). The opening looked like it was going to be something more adult, with Jill in a closet and tentacles beginning to worm their way down her shirt through her neckline. I forget what exactly happened after that... I think maybe the tentacles found a grenade, pin already pulled? Jill dove away from the explosion, and stood in triumph... only for Nemesis to step out of the dust cloud, entirely unharmed. Jill proceeds to pull out a variety of weapons, just kind of pulling them out of nowhere, but nothing works. I think I remember a pistol, a military-style rifle, and an RPG.

I think maybe she tries to engage it in close-quarters combat, striking it, grappling it, and trying to use her knife and various bits of the scenery, but all to no avail. Then, it either strikes or throws her, sending her crashing into a bookcase, noticeably bloody and dazed. A flower pot on the bookbase falls on her head, and she stares up at the plant on her head before snatching it and eating it, healing her wounds, probably because it was a [green herb](https://residentevil.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Herb). Nemesis does something to offend her and, in comedic fashion, she's able to beat him down easily, with that, I think, ending the animation.

Comment: "The opening looked like it was going to be something more adult": at this point I thought there was no other kind of RE fanmade video :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saw the same thing on Facebook. [Found it, so there you go](https://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/719888).

[RESIDENT EVIL 3 EPIC PARODY PART 2 by Naga Arjun. R](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbaxPNaZIsk)

Comment: It would be better if you could link directly to the animation instead of a page that embeds it; is it on YouTube?

Comment: Aw bleak @DavidW it _is_ on YouTube but it's age gated so the inline player doesn't work so well. I don't know what to do in this case

Comment: That looks like the one! Thank you.